# Calculating limits with Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: limits, wolfram-alpha

in a random graph setting with $n$ vertices and edge-probability $p$ I want to show that $\binom n4p^6\to 0$ as $pn^{2/3}\to 0$. To check this is even true, I submitted [this Wolfram|Alpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28n%20choose%204%29%20*%20p%5E6%20as%20%28p*n%5E%282%2F3%29%29-%3E0).

Now why does Wolfram|Alpha calculate the limit for $n\to pn^{2/3}$ rather than $pn^{2/3}\to 0$? Is it just a misinterpretation, or is there a mathematical connection I fail to see? Surprisingly it yields the desired result ...

I also don't quite understand what Wolfram|Alpha does in the next line, and I am not even sure how to calculate the limit manually, so I'd be grateful for any insight!

Comment: Be careful wolframalpha is not perfect, sometimes can fail. The best thing you can do is evaluate yourself.

Comment: I know. It gives the right result though so I wondered if one can somehow transform $pn^{2/3}\to 0$ to $n\to pn^{2/3}$. Is there a straightforward way of evaluating such limits manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $pn^{2/3}=\varepsilon$ and then $\varepsilon\to0$.

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28x%5Cto%200%29%20%5Bbinomial%28n%2C4%29%28x%5E6*n%5E%7B-4%7D%29%5D)

Comment: Where does the $n^{-4}$ in your query come from?

Comment: $p=\varepsilon.n^{-2/3}$, and so $p^6=\varepsilon ^6.n^{-4}$

Comment: Ah, I see. Would you say it is obvious that the limit is $0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, or does it need more reasoning?

Comment: $\binom{n}{4}$ is $o(n^4)$ and $n\to\infty$ so $p\to 0$ does it

Comment: Wait why do we have $n\to\infty$?

Comment: what happens otherwise?

Comment: I see that $n\to\infty$ is convenient because we want $\binom n4/n^4$ small. I just wasn't sure that it's okay to assume $n\to\infty$ (and still have $\epsilon\to 0$). Is it because in $pn^{2/3}$, $n$ has a smaller power than $p$?

Comment: you make $p$ a lot smaller than $n^{2/3}$

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, in wolfram alpha you can't have the product of two variables approach a value. In fact you only can have one variable approach a value. You would have to change it so one variable is approaching a certain value. If you want to keep it like you have it, then this is a job for mathematica, not wolfram alpha. See:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables